# SQL Server *= operator

Tags: sql, operators, sql-server-2000

I came across some code with this `*=` operator in a `WHERE` clause and I have only found one thing that described it as some sort of join operator for Sybase DB. It didn't really seem to apply. I thought it was some sort of bitwise thing (which I do not know much about) but it isn't contained in [this reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276846%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) at all.

When I change it to a normal `=` operator it doesn't change the result set at all.

The exact query looks like this:

```
select distinct 
       table1.char8_column1,
       table1.char8_column2,
       table2.char8_column3,
       table2.smallint_column
from   table1, table2
where  table1.char8_column1 *= table2.another_char8_column
```

Does anyone know of a reference for this or can shed some light on it? This is in SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Kill the deprecated syntax if you can, but:

```
*= (LEFT JOIN)

=* (RIGHT JOIN)
```

Answer (score 5):

That would be the "old school" equivalent of a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).

Answer (score 3):

It is legacy syntax for specifying outer joins, Microsoft refers to it as "non-ANSI outer join operators". These outer join operators (*= and =*) are not supported when the compatibility level of the database is set to 90.

This question has been answered on StackOverflow before: [What is this operand (*= star-equals) in SQL server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269845/what-is-this-operand-star-equals-in-sql-server-2000)