# Incorrect syntax near ' *= ' in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT  LM.LocationName ,
        PPD.RegistrationNo ,
        ISNULL(PPD.Title, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(PPD.FirstName, '') + ' '
        + ISNULL(PPD.LastName, '') AS CustomerName ,
        PPD.RegistrationDate ,
        PPD.Ref_By_Patient ,
        ISNULL(PPD1.Title, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(PPD1.FirstName, '') + ' '
        + ISNULL(PPD1.LastName, '') AS Ref_By_PatientName ,
        PPD.Mobile ,
        PPD.Res_Telephone ,
        PPD.Off_Telephone ,
        PPD.EMail ,
        KB.KwnBy ,
        RTM.RegType ,
        PPD.Street ,
        AM.area_name ,
        CM.city_name ,
        DM.DoctorName ,
        PPD.SpecialDiscount ,
        PPD.SpecialDisPercentage ,
        PPD.ServiceDisPercentage ,
        PPD.Type ,
        PPD.TypeChangedDate
FROM    Patient_Personal_Details PPD ,
        LocationMaster LM ,
        KnownBy KB ,
        Area_Master AM ,
        RegTypeMaster RTM ,
        City_Master CM ,
        Doctor_Master DM ,
        Patient_Personal_Details PPD1
WHERE   PPD.Loc_Id = LM.LocationCode
        AND PPD.Knownby*=CAST(KB.Knwid AS VARCHAR(25))
        AND PPD.Area*=AM.area_id
        AND PPD.City*=CM.city_id
        AND PPD.Doctorname*=DM.Doctor_Id
        AND PPD.RegTypeId*=RTM.RegTypeId
        AND PPD.Ref_By_Patient*=PPD1.RegistrationNo
        AND PPD.RegistrationDate >= '01-Oct-2013'
        AND PPD.RegistrationDate <= '10-Dec-2013'
ORDER BY LM.LocationName ,
        PPD.RegistrationNo
```

**Error**

> Incorrect syntax near '*='.

Please advise

Comment: it hurts my eyes. ouch.

Comment: why are you using that operator? You are multipying IDs!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago). And that includes the `=*` and `*=` operators - stop using those **RIGHT NOW** and switch to the proper `JOIN` syntax, and all your problems will magically go away ....

Answer (score 5):

`*=` was used as a shortcut syntax for left outer join, whereas `=*` was a shortcut for a right outer join.  Instead of using the `left outer join tablex on x.col1 = ...` syntax, those join fields are being listed in the where clause.  Personally, I'd migrate away from joining in the where clause.

[What is this operand (*= star-equals) in SQL server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269845/what-is-this-operand-star-equals-in-sql-server-2000)

Maybe this was removed in 2012?  try changing the database compatibility mode back one version to 9 (2005) or 10 (2008).